# Error when inserting a table in LyX

Tags: tables, errors, lyx

I am preparing a research proposal and everything was going very well until I inserted a table. It gives me this error. Even if I use the code mode, I get the same error. I believe its a package problem but I dont know what is it and how to fix it.

```
    \begin{tabular}
                     {|c|c|c|}
I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.
```

Can you help me please ?

---

In case you need it, this is my header :

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,english]{book}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in,headheight=12pt,headsep=25pt,footskip=30pt}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[unicode=true,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}
```

Comment: the error must be before the tabular. Did you insert the tabulat vis the LyX tabular menu?

Comment: Yes I just used the menau : Insert/Table.

Comment: Can you post a minimal working example ( http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample )? Maybe you're missing the table-related LaTeX package?